# Unable to get JSON response from cross domain AJAX request

Tags: ajax, extjs

I'm using a JSON store in ExtJS and getting the data from an ASP.net web service. It returns the data successfully if I use it in the same domain, but in a cross-domain it returns an error:

> XMLHTTPREQUEST Access-Control-Origin Header is not allowed by the
>   Origin

Here is my code:

```
var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    // Load data at once
    autoLoad: true,

    // Override default http proxy settings
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        // Call web service method using GET syntax
        type:'ajax',
        url: path+'SelectIncidentList',
        restful:true,

        // Ask for Json response
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
        reader:    {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'd'
        },
    }),

    id: 'incidentid',

    // Fields declaration
    fields: ['incidentid','occured','headline','source','enteredby','bodyintro','webaddress','location1','location2','location3','location4','image','incidenttypeid','incidentsubtypeid']
});
```

---

*** EDIT ***

Based off the answers I got, I changed my code to use JSONP. However I am running into another issue. With these changes to my ExtJS code:

```
var myStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
autoLoad: true,

// Override default http proxy settings
proxy: new Ext.data.proxy.JsonP({
    type:'jsonp',
    url: path+'SelectoccurList',
    headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'd'
    },
}),
id: 'occurid',

// Fields declaration
fields: ['occurid','occured','headline','source','enteredby','bodyintro','webaddress','location1','location2','location3','location4','image','occurtypeid','occursubtypeid']
});
```

I am running into the following error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
**SelectOccurList:-1Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type      text/xml.
SelectOccurList:1SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'**
<ArrayOfOccurData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<OccurData>
   <occurid>22</occurid>
   <occured>2012-05-26T04:33:53-04:00</occured>
   <headline>headline</headline>
   <source>content</source>
 <enteredby />
 <bodyintro>content</bodyintro>
<webaddress />
<location1>29 -156.364</location1>
<location2 />
<location3 />
<location4 />
<image>url of iamge</image>
<occurtypeid>0</occurtypeid>
<occursubtypeid>0</occursubtypeid>
</OccurData>
<OccurData>
 <occurid>23</occurid>
 <occured>2012-05-26T15:41:52-04:00</occured>
 <headline>headline</headline>
 <source>test content</source>
 <enteredby />
 <bodyintro>test content</bodyintro>
 <webaddress />
 <location1>27.75974 -82.67853</location1>
 <location2 />
 <location3 />
 <location4 />
  <image>url of image</image>
<occurtypeid />
<occursubtypeid />
 </OccurData>
<OccurData>
  <occurid>24</occurid>
  <occured>test</occured>
  <headline />
  <source />
  <enteredby />
  <bodyintro />
  <webaddress />
  <location1 />
  <location2 />
  <location3 />
  <location4 />
  <image />
  <occurtypeid>0</occurtypeid>
  <occursubtypeid>0</occursubtypeid>
 </OccurData>
<OccurData>
 <occurid>25</occurid>
 <occured>Testing</occured>
 <headline>Testing 28 05 </headline>
 <source>Dummy</source>
 <enteredby>XYZ</enteredby>
 <bodyintro>This occur is dummy</bodyintro>
 <webaddress>http://</webaddress>
 <location1>5cd41415-5c60-4cbd-a6f3-05330b368a41</location1>
 <location2 />
 <location3 />
 <location4 />
 <image />
 <occurtypeid>0</occurtypeid>
 <occursubtypeid>0</occursubtypeid>
```

Comment: Have you read this? https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_Access_Control

Answer (score 4):

That's exactly what you'd use a [JsonP proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP) for, which uses a script tag + callback function to get around the same domain browser restriction. The linked header documentation explains it fully with example code, including a few basic server implementations.

The other option would be to actually proxy the call on your server -- i.e., the Ajax proxy calls your server, which then calls the remote server and formats a standard JSON response back to your client.  You just can't make the call directly from client to remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your server to setting "access-control-" headers.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control

Comment: Yes, but just be sure to note the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control#Browser_compatibility) before you do this as your only solution.